# Directly loading a custom Angular app from bundle.js in another Angular app

Tags: angular, webpack

TLDR: How do I build an Angular app to be consumed by another Angular app, directly from the files compiled by webpack?

---

I am new to web programming in Angular so bare with me. I have a legacy Angular 15 app that is a platform for delivering content sets to the web. The platform consists of a main app and several sub-modules. One of the modules has gotten a lot of use, but users are starting to ask for conflicting configurations. My goal is to spin off the module so the users can develop there own module and include it in their deployments without the changes being PR-ed back into the main app.

I already have a development environment that they use to create content sets that gets consumed by the main app. The development environment is an ExpressJS app that statically loads the source of the main app. They can then run the dev env to build and test content sets that eventually get published to a web app. I would publish the sub-module to npmjs, but that will make development on the sub-module a PITA for them.

---

The main component has an Angular component called `custom-app` that loads `./assets/index.html`.

./src/app/custom-app

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-app',
  templateUrl: './custom-app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-app.component.css']
})
export class CustomAppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('container', {static: true}) container: ElementRef
  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient
  ) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    const index = await this.http.get('./assets/index.html', {responseType: 'text'}).toPromise()
    this.container.nativeElement.innerHTML = index
  }

}
```

I can load a separate component built with LitElement with

./components/index.html

```
<custom-app></custom-app>
```

./components/index.js

```
import './components/custom-app.js'
```

The source for `./components/custom-app.js` is webpacked and loaded in the main component

./src/app/index.html

```
<script type="module" src="./assets/custom-scripts.js" defer></script>
```

Is there a way I can do this with another Angular app instead?

Tried:

1. Set up webpack config to output a single `bundle.js` file
2. Run `ng build`
3. Copy `dist/bundle.js` --> `assets/custom-scripts.js`
4. Run `ng serve`

I can't seem to get it to load the custom-app components.